# how to create UUID for reactnative

Tags: react-native

In my application I'll store the some data's,
so I would use the AsyncStorage method but Now need to create a uuid
because AsyncStorage name for same to updated.

any alternative idea for this scenario or how to create UUID.

Not used any npm pakage.

Comment: Do you mean creating a js function that will generate a uuid for you ?

Answer (score 22):

First run the script to install npm package for react-native-uuid

```
   npm install react-native-uuid --save
```

After that import the module in your file by

```
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
//usage 
var testUUID = uuid.v1();
```

You might get an error showing that

> module buffer does not exist in react native

if so, install that module too,

```
 npm install buffer --save
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This generates an error like so: "attempted to import the Node standard library module "buffer". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library."

Answer (score 6):

Without using a npm already tested code you can create you own function that will generate an **UUID** for you.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to install uuid-random using.

`npm i uuid-random`

Then to import,

`import uuid from 'uuid-random';`

Finally to use,

`uuid()`

[More about uuid-random package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-random)

Answer (score 1):

We just recently released an updated version of `react-native-uuid`, fully rewritten in TypeScript.

Here's how to use it:

1. Install

```sh
npm install react-native-uuid
```

2. Call

```js
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
uuid.v4(); // ⇨ '11edc52b-2918-4d71-9058-f7285e29d894'
```

More details:
https://github.com/eugenehp/react-native-uuid

Answer (score 0):

try `expo-crypto`, code:

```js
import { randomUUID } from 'expo-crypto';
console.log(randomUUID())
```

> The randomUUID() method returns a unique identifier based on the V4 UUID spec (RFC4122). It uses cryptographically secure random values to generate the UUID.

install: [expo-crypto](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/)